# How to protect an input from ESD?

Tags: zener, esd, schottky, diode-clamp

I would like to protect the input of a sensor (reference : MAX30001) from ESD.

In the datasheet, they say that the absolute maximum rating of this input is -0.3 V < V<sub>input</sub> < 2 V.

Do I have to strictly respect the given interval ? If yes, I do not know how to do it.

If I put a simple Zener like this :

[image]

The voltage of the input would be between - V<sub>forward</sub> and +V<sub>breakdown</sub>. Problem : forward voltages of Zener diodes are 0.7 V, and I cannot find a breakdown voltage below 3 V.

If I put two clamping diodes like this :

[image]

The voltage of the input would be between - V<sub>forward</sub> and V<sub>dd</sub> + V<sub>forward</sub>. Problem : V<sub>dd</sub> is 1.8 V and I cannot find diodes with a forward voltage of 0.2 V.
What clamping diode do we typically use ? Schottky diodes ?

What other solutions do I have ?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Could you please give a schematic of where the inputs that you like to protected are placed?

Comment: Series diodes that clamp in forward bias. TVS diodes also exist. Similar to zeners. But from the sounds of your application, leakage might screw things up.

Comment: Why isn't the built-in ESD protection not enough? Did you even check how much it can already tolerate? How much protection do you need?

Comment: @justme Oh yeah, it already has ESD protection, and not just for handling during manufacture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What other solutions do I have ?*

Given that the data sheet says this: -

Maximum Current into Any Pin.........................................±50mA

It gives you some leeway to add a resistor in series with the input pin.

But you also need to know how big a resistor can be used and there's a clue on page 14: -

[image]

So, I estimate that the inputs are at least 50 MΩ and so a 1 kΩ in series with each input isn't going to have much of a performance implication.

> *How to protect an input from ESD?*

So, at a maximum current of 50 mA, the voltage drop across 1 kΩ is 50 volts i.e. plenty of headroom to add a TVS of 10 volts or 20 volts on the non-chip side of the input resistor. I wouldn't use a zener - use a TVS or TVS array suitably specified for protecting against ESD.

And, as @Justme points out, the device has the following level of ESD protection built in: -

[image]

Note 10 says: ESD test performed with 1kΩ series resistor designed to withstand 8kV surge voltage.

So, I guess 1 kΩ (as I derived above) is perfectly sensible. However, given that I have suggested using an external TVS in front of the 1 kΩ that resistor need not be rated at 8 kV: -

[image]

Comment: The datasheet also specifies how much ESD the device can take with 1k resistance.

Comment: Oh does it. That's cool @Justme

Comment: No, the resistor doesn't need to be rated 8kV. That's if you want to match the maximum voltage of the TVS diode and still have current crossing it to activate the sensor. But any resistor would add a protection. The goal of this resistor is to prevent current from reaching the ic before the TVS diode starts clamping. Ideally no current should have the time to cross the resistor. You can use 10k as well. The value is only limited to the sensitivity of the sensor ic. Since the impedance is already abovce 50M, 10K won;t make much a difference. Maybe 100K too.

Comment: There is something I do not understand. With the protection circuit you showed, if an +8 kV ESD happens, how do I know the current which will flow in the resistance and the voltage drop across the resistance ?
With a 3V TVS, the current cannot be higher than : I = U/R = 3 / 1000 = 3 mA, but the is the upper limit, how can I be sure the voltage drop will be high enough to ensure that the voltage at the input is below 2 V ?

Comment: @JackOfHearts First of all, the max input voltage is +2.3 volts and, at this voltage on an input, you want to prevent more than 50 mA flowing (i.e. the input pin voltage rises 0.3 volts above the AVdd and the internal diodes start clamping). 50 mA is mentioned in the AMR section BTW and if this is exceeded you get problems. So, if you assume the input pin voltage is at maximum i.e. 2.3 volts and there is a 1 kohm series resistor protecting it, what voltage (Vmax) could you tolerate on the the resistor input before 50 mA flows. In other words re-arrange (Vmax - 2.3)/50 mA to get 1000 ohms.....

Comment: .... so Vmax = 52.3 volts. That is the maximum voltage that you could have to ground at the input to the resistor before the AMRs are exceeded. So you choose a TVS of (say) 10 volts and steer clear. With 10 volts being Vmax on one side of the resistor and 2.3 volts being on the other side, the volt drop is 7.7 volts and this means a current (worst case) of 7.7 mA into the input circuit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is more clear now, I am just missing a point : why can we consider the input pin voltage of the IC is 2.3 V ? Why not something else ? Is it because when an ESD happens, the internal clamping diode is conducting thus imposing 2.3 V ?
Moreover, the point of staying between -0.3 V and 2.3 V is to prevent the internal diodes of the component from clamping, is that right ?  Why is it a problem ?

Comment: @JackOfHearts yes, the internal clamping diode starts to activate and we must keep that current well below 50 mA. If we allowed the internal clamps too much current, the chip can [latch-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up) and the chip self-destruct.

Answer (score 0):

If the absolute maximum ratings are "-0.3 V < Vinput < 2 V" you will have to make sure the voltage always is within this limits.

I would firstly try to find some ready made ESD protection IC, or TVS diode packages for the voltage category.

For input power protection you could place a ferrite bead with ESD protection on both sides of it, to make it harder for the fast signal ESD to penetrate the high impedance of the ferrite bead.
You can also use a resistor (with the same principle) if you can tolerate the dissipation power, I would only use it on low power devices. However beware that the resistor can handle the Puls peak power when the device is turned on until the decoupling capacitor is charged.